# How I can make changes to XConnect model without crashing CD instance

Tags: xconnect, contact-facets

I have a custom facet with multiple properties.

I deployed the model to xConnect and it's working on Production servers on Azure now.

Now I need to modify the facet. Let's say - I need to remove one of the properties.

My release mechanism switches the CD LIVE slot with CD BACKUP slot (and the `web` db copy), deploys code and items to CM and CD LIVE slot. When everything is completed, the traffic is again switched to the fresh and new CD LIVE.

The problem is that if I deploy the new model to xConnect, CD BACKUP slot, which doesn't have new dlls yet, will start throwing `XdbModelConflictException`: `'CustomXdbModel, 1.0' does not match the remote version`, right?

And I cannot deploy 2 versions of the same model to xConnect as that will cause `Different models with the same names are referenced ('CustomXdbModel')` issue, right?

Any ideas how to proceed in a situation like that without any interruption in gathering and processing contact data?

Comment: I have no simple plan when I deploy my models. You can't have two of the same models with different versions. And if you change the model name, you can't have two model with the same Facet model. Catch 22. Stinks.

Comment: Can you make sure your xConnect code is wrapped in a if (Tracker.Enabled) {} and then disable xDB when you deploy your models. You will miss out on data during the deployment, but the site will keep running.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisAuer but I cannot really change all the code which uses tracker.